# How to capture a click event on a buried DIV but not anything contained in the DIV when the DIV doesn't initially exist in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have a vanilla Javascript event listener that's passing data exactly how I want it... except when I click on text that has been bolded, or italicized, or is otherwise encapsulated. Here's my test javascript:

```
window.onclick = function(e){
        if(e.target.dataset.lb_action){
                console.log(e.target.dataset);
        }
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div><div data-lb_action=99>This text works but <b>this text doesn't</b></div></div>
```

If I click on "This text works but" I get my expected console report: `DOMStringMap(1) { lb_action → "99" }`. But if I click on "this text doesn't" the DOMStringMap is empty. I believe it's picking up the (yes, I know, deprecated) Bold tag inside the DIV tag.

Remember, that entire string of HTML doesn't initially exist when the page is built. It's dynamically loaded later. Is there a way I can force the event handler to pick up the DIV I'm interested in? I hoped the IF statement would solve that problem by picking the right data out of the bubble path. But it's not working. I've tried using an IF for the DIV "id" tag, but that also doesn't work.

How can I capture the "Data-" information out of the one DIV that matters in the DOM chain when that DIV doesn't initially exist?

Comment: Use `e.currentTarget` to get the element that the event listener was attached to, rather than the element you clicked on.

Comment: @Barmar Currently the event listener is attached to `window.`, wouldn't `.currentTarget` simply pick up the top-most parent?

Comment: You can use `e.target.closest("div")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `closest()` method to find the containing `div`.

Since `window` doesn't have a `dataset` property, I've used conditional chaining when testing for `lb_action` to prevent an error.

```js
window.onclick = function(e) {
  let container = e.target.closest("div");
  if (container?.dataset.lb_action) {
    console.log(container.dataset);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-lb_action=99>This text works but <b>this text doesn't</b></div>
</div>
```